# StringBuilder пропускает пустые строки java

Tags: java, android

Здраствуйте, в данном куске кода пытаюсь вывести весь текст с файла, но почему-то пропускаються пустые строки.

```
public StringBuilder readFile(String data_file) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
    
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                context.openFileInput(data_file)));

       String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
           stringBuilder.append(line);
     }
        Log.d("Pasichnik","Log VAlueTextEdit"+stringBuilder);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stringBuilder;
}
```

Comment: а что такое context?

Comment: Это контекст активити в котором исполняется данные клас.

Comment: `BufferedReader.readLine()` возвращает текст без символов перевода строки - их нужно добавлять самому: `stringBuilder.append(line).append('\n');` А вообще незачем читать текст построчно если вы не собираетесь что-то искать в строках и вам нужен весь текст целиком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил это так:

```java
public StringBuilder readFile(String data_file) {
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // открываем поток для чтения
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(context.getFilesDir()+"/"+data_file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stringBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Если пустая строка должна быть разделителем, то:

```
 stringBuilder.append(line.isEmpty() ? "\n" : line);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: разделяет, но пустые строки  все равно пропускает